# Cartesian product of two manifolds and tangent spaces

Tags: manifolds, submanifold, tangent-bundle

I have an $n$ dimensional parallelizable manifold $M$. I know that *it is* the cartesian product of two parallelizable manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ but I *do not know* these two manifolds, not even their dimensions $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Note 1: the factorization into $M_1\times M_2$ could be non-unique. Please, assume that it is, for now, then read the note at the end. And assume that $M_1$ and $M_2$ have at least dimension 1.

I am wondering if I can get some information about $M_1$ and $M_2$, e.g. the dimensions $n_1$ and $n_2$, by knowing the following fact. I have $n$ vector fields $v_j$; I know that they generate the tangent space of $M$, and that each of them belongs either:

1. to the tangent space of $M_1\times \{m_2\}$, where $m_2 \in M_2$, or
2. to the tangent space of $M_2\times \{m_1\}$, where $m_1 \in M_1$.

However, I do not know which $v_j$ belongs to one or the other group.

Is there any way to evaluate at least the dimensions of $M_1$ or $M_2$?
Any suggestion is welcome!

Note 2: in case the factorization is not unique, I would like to find one of the possible factorizations, using the $v_j$, or at least the dimensions $n_1$ and $n_2$ of a couple of possible factors.

Comment: I think $M=\Bbb R^4$, $M_1\times\{m_2\}=\Bbb R\times\{(0,0,0)\}$, $\{m_1\}\times M_2=\{0\}\times\Bbb R^3$, $M'_1\times\{m'_2\}=\Bbb R^2\times\{(0,0)\}$, $\{m'_1\}\times M'_2=\{(0,0)\}\times\Bbb R^2$, and $v_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the factorization of a manifold is not unique. I modify my question to clarify this.

Comment: In the question, $n$ is both the dimension of $M$ and the number of vector fields "[generating] the tangent space of $M$." Are those intentionally the same number? Particularly, are we assuming $M$, $M_1$, and $M_2$ are parallelizable? <> Whether or no, can you perhaps edit the question to say more about how $M$ is presented, and how the vector fields are given?

Comment: Yes, the manifolds are parallelizable. The problem that I am describing is a step in a proof, so I do not really have  the v_j in the sense that I have an expression for them. Rather, I know in general how to calculate them. If you are interested, I can explain more in detail. I will not include this explanation in the question because it would make it too technical.

Comment: What you wrote is obviously insufficient to determine $n_1$ and $n_2$. Just consider the product of two open orientable surfaces of positive genus vs. the product of $S^3$ and the real line.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you show an example of $M$ that can be factorized with $n_1=n_2=2$ and also with $n_1=3$ and $n_2=1$. Please let me know if I misunderstood or I missed something. My point is that this cannot be always done. I.e. there are manifolds that can be factorized with a given $n_1$ and $n_2=n-n_1$, but cannot be factorized with other $n_1$ and $n_2=n-n_1$. Am I wrong? If I am correct, than my question makes sense, with reference to these cases.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. If you want me to get a notification of your replies to me, add @[my username] in your comment.

Comment: Just to be sure, @Moishe Kohan: you think that there are cases in which there can be some $n_1$ but not others. Then, my question makes sense: do you think that some property of the vectors $v_j$ can be of use to find at least one of the suitable $n_1$?